# The $n$-th derivative of $x^2(x+1)^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I need to find the derivative of $x^2(x+1)^n$.

I need to use Leibniz formula but I just can't get the result.
We are supposed to get this :
[image: Correct Result]

But I got nearly the same kind :
$$x^2n! + 2xn!(x+1) + 2\frac{n!}{2!}(x+1)^2$$
$$= n!(x^2 + 2x(x+1) + (x+1)^2 $$
[image: My Work]
It starts from the mess below the horizontal line.
So I don't know how to get the result. I really can't understand what I did wrong. I succeeded in similar questions like nth derivative of $(x-a)^n(x-b)^n$.
I would really appreciate it if someone could lend a hand.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really difficult to read your writing; for me to try to detect where you might have made a calculation error would probably take longer than to just write my own step-by-step solution.

Let $f(x) = x^2$, $g(x) = (x+1)^n$, and $h(x) = f(x)g(x) = x^2 (x+1)^n$.  Then we want
$$h^{(n)}(x) = (fg)^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f^{(k)}(x) g^{(n-k)}(x). \tag{1}$$

As you observed, $f^{(k)}(x) = 0$ for all $k > 2$, so the sum on the RHS in Equation $(1)$ only contains $3$ terms.  These require the evaluation of $g^{(n-k)}(x)$ for $k \in \{0, 1, 2\}$.  To this end, we observe
$$\begin{align}
g'(x) &= n(x+1)^{n-1} , \\
g''(x) &= n(n-1)(x+1)^{n-2} , \\
&\vdots \\
g^{(m)}(x) &= n(n-1)\cdots(n-m+1)(x+1)^{n-m} = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!} (x+1)^{n-m}, \quad m \in \{1, \ldots, n\}. \tag{2}
\end{align}$$  So now letting $m \in \{n-2, n-1, n\}$ in Equation $(2)$ gives in particular
$$\begin{align}
g^{(n-2)}(x) &= \frac{n!}{2!} (x+1)^2 = \frac{n!}{2} (x+1)^2, \\
g^{(n-1)}(x) &= \frac{n!}{1!} (x+1)^1 = n! (x+1), \\
g^{(n)}(x) &= \frac{n!}{0!} (x+1)^0 = n!.
\end{align}$$
It follows that
$$\begin{align}
h^{(n)}(x) &= \binom{n}{0} f(x) g^{(n)}(x) + \binom{n}{1} f'(x) g^{(n-1)}(x)  + \binom{n}{2} f''(x) g^{(n-2)}(x) \\
&=  (x^2) n! + n (2x) n!(x+1) + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} (2) \frac{n!}{2}(x+1)^2 \\
&= n! \left( x^2 + 2nx(x+1) + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}(x+1)^2 \right).
\end{align}$$

---

Upon examination of your handwritten notes, I think I have found your error.  You wrote
$$h^{(n)}(x) = \binom{\color{red}{2}}{0} f(x) g^{(n)}(x) + \binom{\color{red}{2}}{1} f'(x) g^{(n-1)}(x)  + \binom{\color{red}{2}}{2} f''(x) g^{(n-2)}(x)$$ where the red text is incorrect; the upper index of the binomial coefficients must be $n$, not $2$, even though there are only three terms in the sum.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really took me more than 3 hours. Im never again replacing n, never.

Answer (score 2):

A small amount of cleverness makes this much more tractable, and avoids combinatorics:

Namely, the leading factor of $x^2$ is $(x+1)^2-2(x+1)+1$. So the whole expression can be expressed in powers of $x+1$, as
$$
 \Big((x+1)^2-2(x+1)+1\Big)\cdot (x+1)^n
\;=\; (x+1)^{n+2} - 2(x+1)^{n+1} + (x+1)^n
$$
Thus, the derivative is
$$
(n+1)(x+1)^{n+1} - 2(n+1)(x+1)^n + n(x+1)^{n-1}
$$
Rearrange to taste. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the [binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) $(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}x^k1^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}x^k$

$$g(x)=x^2(x + 1)^n = x^2\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}x^k$$
$$= \sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}x^{k + 2}$$

We have

$$g^{(1)}(x)= \sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}(k+2)x^{k + 1}$$
$$g^{(2)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}(k+2)(k+1)x^k$$
$$g^{(3)}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}(k+2)(k+1)kx^{k-1}$$
$$g^{(4)}(x)=\sum_{k=2}^n\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}(k+2)(k+1)k(k-1)x^{k-2}$$
If we continue with this pattern we obtain

$$g^{(n)}(x) = \sum_{k=n-2}^n\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}(k+2)(k+1)k(k-1)\ldots (k-n+3)x^{k-n+2}$$

Now, evaluate these three terms of the sum, and you are done.

Comment: I don't understand what you did. Arent we supposed to use Leibniz formula since it is a product fo two functions. And I can't get the pattern: it stopped making sense at the third line

Comment: @EyePatch Once you apply the binomial theorem, you have a polynomial, which is very easy to differentiate.

Comment: Honestly, I'm having a hard time understanding how to get the derivative of a binomial theorem. I know what it does. But why use that when we can use Leibniz? I'm really focusing on Leibniz Theorem since we didn't see how to get the derivative of binomial.
But What I know is that : $((x+1)^n)^(k)$ is equal to $$frac\{n!}{(n-k)!}(x+1)^(n-k)$$

Comment: @EyePatch: Leibniz formula is useful for products but not for polynomials. Polynomials are very easy to differentiate. It is a sum. As the differential operator is linear it is only necessary that you differentiate the powers. Differentiating $x^m$ is pretty simple.

Comment: I see, yea it is pretty simple for $x^m$. I'll study the approach in the answer more. However the answer provided @heropup is what i was looking for and it seems much more simple personally

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^2(x+1)^n$. One has $$f(x)=x^2(x+1)^n = x^{n+2} + nx^{n+1} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^n + P(x)$$

where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. Hence
$$\boxed{f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{(n+2)!}{2}x^2 + n(n+1)!x + \frac{n(n-1)n!}{2}}$$